# Deal with Restler versioning

Tags: php, api, version, versioning, restler

I'm trying to use Restler versioning but there is something i don't get.

On the [BMI example](http://restler3.luracast.com/examples/_011_versioning/readme.html) it's written that:

> Only integers are supported for versioning. When not specified explicitly the version is assumed to be one.

But in your example, the v2 is explicitly specified with:

```
$r->setAPIVersion(2);
```

... and the default version when accessing **/_011_versioning/bmi.json** is still v1 !

So I don't get it, what the setAPIVersion() function really do ? Maybe I miss some documentation part (my English isn't that fluent)

Thanks you again for your quick and efficient support (not the first time I'm asking questions here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- By calling setAPIVersion we are setting the maximum api version we support
- We want to support existing api users with out braking their app, thats why we need to serve version 1 when the api user does not specify a version
- Once the user is ready to user v2 of the api, they will request for v2 by

  - specifying version in the url, if we support url based versioning
  - specifying version in the header, if we support vendor media type (which is the next example)

Comment: Thank you ! Exactly as I expected ! 
Another question : Do you know if there is a way to avoid to set all the classes and functions into a "v1" or "v2" namespace ?
Thank you again

Comment: By default, all the classes belongs only in their versions. RC5 adds sine flexibility with `iProvideMultiVersionApi` interface by implementing it in your api, you can set the maximum supported version. So if v1 of a class needs no change for v2 but needed in v2 api you can make it available